# read gets skipped in here-document

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a script test1.sh. It has rwx permissions for all users. It contains this text :

```
echo "You are in test1.sh"
read -p "Enter some text : " text1
echo "You entered : $text1"
bash <<!
        echo "You are now in a here-document"
        read -p "Enter some more text : " text2
        echo "You also entered : $text2"
        echo "End of the here-document"
!
echo "End of test1.sh"
```

When I run it as sh test1.sh, the second read statement is skipped completely. Here is the output :

```
$ sh test1.sh
You are in test1.sh
Enter some text : hello
You entered : hello
You are now in a here-document
End of the here-document
End of test1.sh
```

When I run it as ./test1.sh, both statements are skipped.

```
$ ./test1.sh
You are in test1.sh
./test1.sh[11]: read: no query process
You entered :
You are now in a here-document
End of the here-document
End of test1.sh
```

If I change test1.sh to use /dev/tty,

```
echo "You are in test1.sh"
read -p "Enter some text : " text1
echo "You entered : $text1"
bash <<!
        echo "You are now in a here-document" > /dev/tty
        read -p "Enter some more text : " text2 < /dev/tty
        echo "You also entered : $text2" > /dev/tty
        echo "End of the here-document" > /dev/tty
!
echo "End of test1.sh"
```

then I get :

```
$ sh test1.sh
You are in test1.sh
Enter some text : hello
You entered : hello
You are now in a here-document
Enter some more text : bye
You also entered :
End of the here-document
End of test1.sh
```

The second text didn't get printed.

If I edit the file to use stdin and stdout,

```
echo "You are in test1.sh"
read -p "Enter some text : " text1
echo "You entered : $text1"
bash <<!
        echo "You are now in a here-document" > /dev/stdout
        read -p "Enter some more text : " text2 < /dev/stdin
        echo "You also entered : $text2" > /dev/stdout
        echo "End of the here-document" > /dev/stdout
!
echo "End of test1.sh"
```

, I get this output :

```
$ sh test1.sh
You are in test1.sh
Enter some text : hello
You entered : hello
You are now in a here-document
You also entered :
End of the here-document
End of test1.sh
```

I couldn't input any text for the second read statement

I want to read input from each read statement into text1 and text2 respectively and I want both $text1 and $text2 to be echo-ed. Could you please tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're processing the here-document, standard input is the rest of the here-document. So in the first script, the second `read` line is reading the `echo` line that comes after it. Since that line is being read by `read`, it doesn't get executed by the shell.

I think the reason for the error in your second script is because you didn't put `#!/bin/bash` at the beginning of the script. Without that, the script is executed by `sh` instead of `bash`, and it doesn't understand the `-p` option to `read`.

In the third script, the reason `$text2` doesn't get echoed is because variables in a here-document are expanded by the shell reading the here-document. But the variable `$text2` is set in the child shell process. You can solve this with `<<'!'` -- putting quotes around the end-marker means that the here-document should be treated as a literal string, and variables should not be expanded.

In the last script, redirecting input from `/dev/stdin` doesn't do anything, because that's where input is already coming from.

Comment: Putting the end-marker in quotes <<'!' while using /dev/tty for input solved the problem! Thanks for explaining and making the code work!

Answer (score 0):

Consider the first script:

```
echo "You are in test1.sh"
read -p "Enter some text : " text1
echo "You entered : $text1"
bash <<!
        echo "You are now in a here-document"
        read -p "Enter some more text : " text2
        echo "You also entered : $text2"
        echo "End of the here-document"
!
echo "End of test1.sh"
```

Where is the standard input of the `bash` coming from? Answer: the here document. So the `read` tries to read from standard input too.  The chances are that the shell has read everything so the `read` comes up empty.

Comment: I didn't understand.. How can I correct it so that I can use "read" to get input from the terminal in both read statements?

Comment: `read -p "Whatever" text2 < /dev/tty`?  Or: `bash -c 'echo "You are now in a here-document";
        read -p "Enter some more text : " text2;
        echo "You also entered : $text2";
        echo "End of the here-document"'` (semicolons added so it would work if copied and pasted).